# issue with Retrieve original value from json

Tags: json, vb.net

New Help to retrieve original value from Json row Data the below code strip some "\"

-------------Json data-----------------

```
{
    "type": "push",
    "targets": ["stream"],
    "push": {
        "type": "mirror",
        "source_device_iden": "ujzp6Xr9A4asjyjskXPzu8",
        "source_user_iden": "ujzp6Xr9A4a",
        "client_version": 354,
        "dismissible": true,
        "icon": "test",
        "title": "ok",
        "body": "Hi",
        "application_name": "android",
        "package_name": "com.android",
        "notification_id": "1",
        "notification_tag": "y9x5Q2YAI\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\n",
        "conversation_iden": "{\"package_name\":\"com.android\",\"tag\":\"y9x5Q2YAI\\\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\\n\",\"id\":1}"
    }
}
```

--------------------  VB code ---------------------------

```
Private Sub jsonData(JsonStr As String)

    Dim json As String = JsonStr
    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
    Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
    Dim Result as string

    For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
        Select Case item.Name

            Case "push"
                For Each msg As JObject In item

                   Result =  msg("conversation_iden")
                Next
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

--------------------------- resulet -----------------------------

Result  = "{"package_name":"com.com.android","tag":"y9x5Q2YAI/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\n","id":1}"

original value :
 "{\"package_name\":\"com.android\",\"tag\":\"y9x5Q2YAI\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\n\",\"id\":1}"

Comment: this get form provider API like this  -----    {\"package_name\":\"com.android\",\"tag\":\"y9x5Q2YAI\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\n\",\"id\":1}"

Comment: The value of `"conversation_iden"` has been double-serialized: a c# object object was serialized into a JSON string which was later added to some container object which was also serialized.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening in the first place?

Comment: Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json.Replace("\","")) and it will work, also inform them that their json is not valid.

Comment: Can you show how you receive this JSON (the code that acquires it)?